# Rectangle not showing up with SDL

Tags: c, sdl

I want a grey rectangle to show up at `100, 100` on the screen.

Here's my code for drawing the block:

```c
void drawBlock() {
  // make the walls gray
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 210, 209, 205, 255);
  SDL_Rect block = {
        .x = 100,
        .y = 100,
        .w = BLOCK_SIZE,
        .h = BLOCK_SIZE
  };

  SDL_RenderFillRect(rend, &block);
}
```

I'm then initializing the function above `int main()`:

```c
void drawBlock();
```

And calling it here:

```c
    /* Clear screen */
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 0, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderClear(rend);

    drawBlock(); //function is called here

    /* Move the rectangle */
    x_vel = (right_pressed - left_pressed)*SPEED;
    y_vel = (down_pressed - up_pressed)*SPEED;

    x_pos += x_vel / 60;
    y_pos += y_vel / 60;

    rect.x = x_pos;
    rect.y = y_pos;

    if (x_pos <= 0) { //Constrain object within screen bounderies
      x_pos = 0;
    }
    if (x_pos >= WIDTH - rect.w) {
      x_pos = WIDTH - rect.w;
    }
    if (y_pos <= 0) {
      y_pos = 0;
    }
    if (y_pos >= HEIGHT - rect.h) {
      y_pos = HEIGHT - rect.h;
    }

    /* Draw the rectangle */
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(rend, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(rend, &rect);
    /* Draw to window and loop */
    SDL_RenderPresent(rend);
    SDL_Delay(1000/FPS);

  } //END OF RUNNING LOOP

  /* Release resources */
  SDL_DestroyRenderer(rend);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();
```

However, the block is not showing up.

Here is my full code, where you can also run it: https://replit.com/@STCollier/OffshoreBoringArguments?v=1

Comment: You have a global variable named `rend` and another one inside main created here: `SDL_Renderer* rend = SDL_CreateRenderer`. Guess which one `DrawBlock` is using...

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks, that fixed the problem. Just how did the global variable mess up the rendering though?

Comment: The global variable is NULL, it doesn't point to the renderer that was created.